# How to get only loaded JSON keys and values from jquerymx Model?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ejs, javascriptmvc

I'm trying to write an ejs Template, which shows all key's and values from an javascript MVC Model. According to this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073837/how-to-get-json-key-and-value) answer, I've tried the following:

```
Person.findOne({id: 51}, function(person) {
     $("#editcustomerform").html('./html/person_2.ejs', person);
});
```

The ejs looks like this:

```
<form id="personForm">
     <table class="ui-widget-content table">
        <thead ><tr>
                <th style=" width: 100px">Feld</th>
                <th>Inhalt</th>
            </tr></thead>

        <tbody>
            <% $.each(this, function(key, value){  %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= key %>:</td>
                <td><input name="<%= key %>" id="<%= key %>" type="text" size="30" maxlength="30" value="<%= value %>"></td>
            </tr>
            <% }) %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

The loaded Data looks like the following:

```
{"id":51,"name":"Max","age":20}
```

Everything is working. The problem is, that all attributes like constructor, Class, update, etc. are shown in the form.
I didn't found a function from JavascriptMVC, which gives me only the loaded Json data.

Do I need to parse the attributes id, name and age manually or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [.hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to tell whether a property belongs to the object itself or was inherited from `Object`.